# Convert a List of Lists that contains integers into a string based on ascii value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, nested-loops

How would I convert a 2D list of integers into a string based on the ascii value? For example, I input [ [97,97,97], [98,98,98] ] and I want the output to be ['aaa', 'bbb']

```
def to_string2(a):
   for subarr in a:
       for ele in subarr:
           ''.join(chr(i) for i in ele)
```

I have the following code, which I've just been typing randomly just to see if I could get something to work, since I don't have a clue on how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```py
lst = [[97,97,97], [98,98,98]]

output = [''.join(map(chr, sublst)) for sublst in lst]
print(output) # ['aaa', 'bbb']
```

To give a fix for your code, the code has an excessive level of `for` loop. Try instead:

```py
output = []
for sublst in lst:
   output.append(''.join(chr(i) for i in sublst))
```

would work.

Comment: Use of `map` makes this the best...

Answer (score 0):

Nesting two `.join` should do the job. Try this:

```
' '.join([''.join([str(el) for el in subarr]) for subarr in arr])
```

Answer (score 0):

You'r doing one too much iteration

- iterate over each sublist `for subarr in a`
- iterate over each int `for ele in subarr`
- **! ! !** you can't iterate over the int `for i in ele`

```
def to_string2(a):
    result = []
    for subarr in a:
        result.append(''.join(chr(ele) for ele in subarr))
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def to_string2(a):
    return ["".join([chr(i) for i in subarr]) for subarr in a]


print(to_string2([[97,97,97], [98,98,98]]))
```